# Drawing video to canvas slow in Firefox

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, canvas, video

Try this fiddle in Chrome and in Firefox.
https://jsfiddle.net/lvl5hm/xosan6w9/29/ 
In Chrome it takes about 0.5-2ms to draw video to canvas, but FF for some reason takes 20-40, which is pretty insane. 
Is there something that can help me improve FF performance?

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
canvas.width = 500
canvas.height = 300

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

const video = document.createElement('video')
video.src = 'https://static.beeline.ru/upload/images/business/delo/newmain/main.mp4'
video.muted = true
video.loop = true
video.oncanplay = () => {
    video.play()
}

const frameCounterElement = document.getElementById('frameCounter')
let duration = 0
setInterval(() => {
    frameCounterElement.innerHTML = duration.toFixed(2) + 'ms to render'
}, 400)

function loop() {
    const startTime = performance.now()
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    duration = performance.now() - startTime

    requestAnimationFrame(loop)
}

loop()
```

Comment: While firfox has the occasional 1ms frame ... I see no discernible difference between Chrum and Firefox

Comment: Seems pretty random indeed, I had some really long frames the first time on your fiddle, but when doing more tests, I just had the same 2~6ms variation as on Chrome.